# 'sudo service apache2 start' doesn't work on ubuntu18.04

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-5

I've installed laravel on my ubuntu18.04.
And I made /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf file.

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.tld

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/your-project/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/your-project>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then run these code on terminal:

```js
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite laravel.conf
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But when I run "sudo service apache2 restart", An error code occurs.

```js
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And I ran both of "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" but there were also error codes:

```js
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-10-29 01:48:17 PDT; 5min ago
  Process: 40882 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu apachectl[40882]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress thi
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu apachectl[40882]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu apachectl[40882]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu apachectl[40882]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu apachectl[40882]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu apachectl[40882]: Action 'start' failed.
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu apachectl[40882]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 29 01:48:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

How can I start Apache Http server.
Somebody help me!

Comment: Have you tried `systemctl start apache2.service ` ?

Comment: what do you get if you run --> 'apache2ctl configtest' , It will show you where is the error in the apache2.conf file to correct .

Comment: The thing that stands out to me is the address already in use error.  Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/277162/apache-fails-to-start-address-already-in-use-but-not-really for troubleshooting this. I'm betting it has something to do with a duplicate `listen` or you have a different service already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this link steps by steps u will get your solution.
its happening only if we config firewall or didnt config firewall  properly.
see this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04